# UITableViewCells Images causing memory growth

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, uitableview

I am currently creating a set of profiles with individualized images (user selectable) for each profile.  The profiles are shown using a UITableViewController created by storyboard.  The code works fine, but when I transition modally to another ViewController using storyboard, the memory for each of the images remain.  If I transition back to the UITableViewController, the memory doubles, and the images seems to be reloaded into the memory.  I am using ARC, and the images are stored in standardUserDefault.  Below is the relevant code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    profiles = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"profileName"] allKeys];
    NSMutableDictionary *temp = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for(NSString *profName in profiles) {
        NSData* imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-image", profName]];
        [temp setObject:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData] forKey:profName];
    }
    images = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:temp];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"profiles";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSString *profName = [profiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:profName];
    cell.imageView.image = [images objectForKey:profName];
    return cell;
}
```

If I replace the line that sets the images for each cell with code such as below:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"];
```

The memory frees up just fine.  I am not doing anything else to free up memory or setting anything to nil in any other part of the code.  Can someone help me identify the way to free up the memory when I transition from the UITableViewController?  I'm also open to suggestions of other ways to save the image the user selects for a profile (from UIImagePickerController).

Comment: Are you sure your view controller is being deallocated? Perhaps there is a retain cycle keeping it around and since you keep a dictionary with all of the images, the memory keeps going up.

Comment: You need to set the images dictionary to nil in viewWillDisappear

Comment: @GuybrushThreepwood Only do that if you populate the images dictionary in `viewWillAppear:`.

Comment: Do you not need to set it to nil so that arc tidy-up will happen ? Edit - oh nm - see what you mean - crash city when you return to the view and the array is gone.

Comment: @GuybrushThreepwood No. It will happen automatically. But that assumes the view controller is being deallocated.

Comment: It also assumes this is the final view in the app structure. If several views are pushed after this view then it may make sense to clean up the memory pro-actively.

Comment: I also assume that the attached images would be deallocated automatically.  That's why when I just used a stock image, everything deallocates normally.  That's why I'm feeling that it's because of the way I'm doing the image dictionary, and the images are retained somehow, thus the whole UITableViewController remains in memory.